# Go Evio application suddenly does not respond. Profiling shows all threads have stopped

Tags: go, profiling

We have an application based on [Evio](https://github.com/tidwall/evio) in docker. When running some network load tests we can see that all threads suddenly dropped, heap is flushed. After few seconds timeout it continues execution as usual. App itself was not restarted, but all Evio threads were dead for ~5 seconds.

What can cause this behavior?

Config:

```
Go 1.14
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Docker version 20.10.6
```

See profiling trace: [image: profiling trace]

Comment: It seems that docker is not involved. Re-tested with bare metal application. Results are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was not in Evio or Go profiling. After more investigation it became clear that all routines are blocked by external service. In our case that was gRPC connection in blocking mode, where other instance was not capable in handling such amount of requests.

This video also can be helpful. It shows similar symptoms and how to analyze them.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V74JnrGTwKA